# What is the difference between the isStopped and closed property of the Subject class?

Tags: rxjs, subject

The class `Subject` has 2 properties `closed` and `isStopped`. I know that closed can be used to check whether the `Subject` can still be subscribed to, but what should `isStopped` be used for exactly?

I am asking this because I am trying to find a way to know when a next operation of a `BehaviourSubject` is completed. Can I use `isStopped` for that or is it used for something else?

Comment: You can check the source code https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts

Comment: i did already so. I can see that isStopped is set to true together with closed, but what exactly is the unique purpose of isStopped as opposed to closed???

Comment: `unsubscribe` sets both to `true` but `isStopped` is also set to `true` on `error` and `complete`. One also throws an exception, the other does not, if being called. There are differences between the 2. Which one you check depends on what you end up calling when you want to stop using the `Subject` instance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The compared behavior of `closed` and `isStopped` can be seen in terms of resultant values after each operation:

- On error:

  - `closed`: `false`
  - `isStopped`: `true`.
- If **Subject** gets completed:

  - `closed`: `false`
  - `isStopped`: `true`.
- If unsubscribed:

  - `closed`: `true`
  - `isStopped`: `true`

This is non-exhaustive just show the commons scenarios.